# Matching vertices between two graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism, pattern-matching

I have a situation where I have two graphs that are supposed to represent the same underlying topology but represent the underlying topology at different resolutions.  My goal is to match vertices between the two graphs.

Let's say the graphs represent a city's street system, with vertices being intersections and edges being streets.  *G1* is a full detail map with alleys, streets, highways, etc... *G2* is an overview map with major roads and highways only.  I want the find all the intersections from *G2* on *G1*.  The edges won't exactly match because there will be intermediate vertices in *G1*.  The node degrees may also not exactly match because *G2* may simplify a round-about intersection to its major streets, but *G1* will also include the side-streets radiating from it.

Comment: Can you assume that there are no overpasses/underpasses? In the particular case where $G_1$ and $G_2$ actually have the same information but you have forgotten how they match up, finding the _graph isomorphism_ between them is believed to be a hard problem in general, but has a linear-time algorithm if the graphs are planar.

Comment: Yea, you may assume there are no overpasses/underpasses.  Speed isn't a huge concern at this stage as the graphs are somewhat small and the processing is done offline; what's the linear-time algorithm?

Comment: x @jsex: I don't know it myself, but googling for `planar graph isomorphism` gives some relevant hits. That doesn't necessarily help with your problem, though -- I merely mentioned it because planarity is known to be helpful in a restricted case of your problem.